# Error using getServerSession with async await

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-auth

I'm trying to use getServerSession() in next.js like this:

```
import Login from "./Login";
import Logged from "./Logged";
import { getServerSession } from "next-auth";

export default async function Nav() {
  const session = await getServerSession();
  console.log(session.user);

  return (
    <nav className="flex justify-end">
      {!session?.user && <Login />}
      {session?.user && <Logged />}
    </nav>
  );
}
```

Login.tsx:

```
"use client";

import { signIn } from "next-auth/react";

export default function Login() {
  return (
    <nav className="flex justify-end">
      <button
        className="text-black cursor-pointer underline text-lg p-6 hover:text-gray-600"
        onClick={() => signIn()}
      >
        Sign In
      </button>
    </nav>
  );
}
```

Logged.tsx (didn't add the functionality yet):

```
export default function Logged() {
  return <button>Sign out</button>;
}
```

However, this makes my website a blank page. If I remove the async await and the getServerSession(), it works fine. I believe the problem is with async await, but getServerSession() doesn't work without it. I am using Typescript and the app directory.

Couldn't find why my website just goes blank because of async await.

Answer (score 0):

From what i remember, you can't export a default async component. Or moreover you should not directly use await getServerSession(). Either use something like getServerSideProps to execute the getServerSession and send the info with props of the pages. Or try to create a state that contain session like this :

```js
export default function Nav() {
  
  const [session, setSession] = useState(null)

  useEffect(()=>{
    const getSession = async () => {
        try{
            const res = await getServerSession();
            if (typeof res === "undefined" || !!!res)
            {
                throw Error("Cannot get server session");
            }
            setSession(res)
        }
        catch (e) 
        {
            console.error(e)
        }

    }
    getSession()
  },[])
  return (
    <nav className="flex justify-end">
      {!session?.user && <Login />}
      {session?.user && <Logged />}
    </nav>
  );
}
```

The documentation of next-auth tell to use getServerSideProps like follow :

```js
import { authOptions } from 'pages/api/auth/[...nextauth]'
import { getServerSession } from "next-auth/next"
export default YourComponent = (props) => {
// ...your component
}
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const session = await getServerSession(context.req, context.res, authOptions)

  if (!session) {
    return {
      redirect: {
        destination: '/',
        permanent: false,
      },
    }
  }

  return {
    props: {
      session,
    },
  }
}
```

See
https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/nextjs
Hope it could respond your answer

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Hades, the above answer doesn't seem to be getting the user, because when I console.log the user I get undefined, and the throw Error doesn't seem to be doing anything.

Comment: Ok, can you try to make a console.log of ```res```, just before setting sessionState and provide the response

Comment: @YusufSaad I suspect that you are using the user variable somewhere in the code before the async function resolves which will throw an error and crashes the application.

You can solve this by doing a conditional render with a loading or a `?.` dot selector which isn't always recommended.

Comment: I got this error: `Error: Invariant: Method expects to have requestAsyncStorage, none available`

Comment: @Dimitar I am not using it before the end of the useEffect(), as I am only using the user in the return statement, and even there, it's a conditional render:
`return (
    <nav className="flex justify-end">
      {!session?.user && <Login />}
      {session?.user && <Logged />}
    </nav>
  );`

Comment: @YusufSaad Please update your question to include all the necessary info.

Answer (score 0):

A *component* can't be `async`.  If you want to fetch data asynchronously in React, the core React concept you're missing is *maintaining state*.  Define a state value to store that data, fetch the data in an effect, and update state.

For example:

```
export default function Nav() {
  const [session, setSession] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const result = await getServerSession();
      setSession(result);
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  console.log(session?.user);

  return (
    <nav className="flex justify-end">
      {!session?.user && <Login />}
      {session?.user && <Logged />}
    </nav>
  );
}
```

Comment: I got this error: Error: Invariant: Method expects to have requestAsyncStorage, none available

Answer (score 0):

A component cannot be an async function, it needs to be a `React Functional Component` or a `React Class Component`

In order to fix the issue you are experiencing, you can call the async function inside of a `useEffect` when the component will mount:

```
import Login from "./Login"
import Logged from "./Logged"
import { useEffect, useState } from "react"
import { getServerSession } from "next-auth"

export default function Nav() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState()
  useEffect(() => {
      const fetchAndSet = async () => {
          try {
              const responseData = await getServerSession()
              setUser(responseData.user)
          } catch (error) {
             // Handle your errors in here
         }
     };

      fetchAndSet()
  }, [])

  return (
    <nav className="flex justify-end">
      {user ? <Logged /> : <Login />}
    </nav>
  );
}
```